# Should I renew my ID card/passport if immigration personnel claims I look different now?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, identity-cards

I got my identity card in August 2014, but have already had problems with it when travelling. In October 2014 while entering Moldova by land, in June 2016 while entering Bulgaria by land, in December 2016 at a boarding gate at Kiev-Boryspil airport, and now in January 2017 when exiting Serbia by land.

Finally, on one occasion in June 2016, I was **outright refused entry to Turkey by land**

The reason each time: the people thought my ID image looked too different from me (also goes for my Turkish entry refusal - while my ID technically isn't valid for Turkey, I've always been fine in practice and the refusal letter I got clearly stated, in a check box, that the reason was that I was an "impostor". I've been able to enter Turkey painlessly since then, however)

At Kiev airport and the Serbian land crossing, my uni-issued student ID saved the day, as I was asked for another ID with a different photograph.

When even the Serbs, the most lazy and nonchalant border guards I've ever dealt with, raise their eyebrows, and the Turks literally call me a fraudster, I can't help starting to wonder whether I should replace it, despite it being only two years old.

I went to a police station in my country and asked, but they found no remarkable difference.

This is an image of me from the day when I exited Serbia

[image]

And this is my ID image

[image]

What do you think?

Comment: You seem to have lost weight and grown your hair.

Comment: Are you willing to live with the doubt and the possible trouble at the borders? If not, get a new ID card. They are not that expensive. There might be a slight bump on your nose on the card photo which is making the difference for the border officials.

Comment: How is this not "primarily opinion-based"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hard time proving I am same person as seen in the passport photo taken 9 years ago](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31311/hard-time-proving-i-am-same-person-as-seen-in-the-passport-photo-taken-9-years-a)

Comment: Honestly, anyone looking at the photo can tell it is you.  The essential face-matching areas are there.  I agree with the police

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at the facts:

1. You're an EU national who uses his ID card to travel
2. You are facing issues at various immigration posts where people don't believe you're the person in the photo
3. You wish to relieve yourself of such problems in the future

I see three possible solutions:

1. Renew your ID, this time taking a photo that looks more like your selfie
2. Cut your hair and gain more weight, so that you look more like the person in the ID card
3. Travel abroad using your passport

Which option is preferable is up to you.