# Can shaving my head cause problems entering the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

Does anyone know about any possible complications that one may face while entering the US with completely shaved head while the passport photo has hair? Many Indians do shave their head as part of the last rites that they perform once their parents die.

Comment: Similar: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21155/can-growing-a-beard-cause-problems-in-crossing-borders?rq=1.  It suggests the answer is "no, you will be just fine."

Answer (score 4):

Should not be an issue. The immigration officers are looking for features that don't change easily.

Answer (score 0):

you might face some delays while people scratch their heads trying to match the photo with your appearance, but you should be fine in the end.
Same with glasses, used to be you'd get some weird looks appearing with different ones from the glasses you had on your passport photo (now of course passport photos are usually required to be made bare faced, without glasses).

Now if you've also had a nose job done, you'd best get a new passport made with a new photo, but just a different hairdo? nah.

Answer (score 0):

If anything, growing a beard might lead to heightened scrutiny. Fortunately, there aren't that many skinhead immigrant terrorists -- most are domestic. As long as you can prove who you are, you should be fine.

[Can growing a beard cause problems in crossing borders?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21155/can-growing-a-beard-cause-problems-in-crossing-borders?lq=1)

Comment: Please consider revising your answer. Specifically **skinhead** is a derogatory term.

Comment: I see no evidence of that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skinhead