# Can I shave my head before going to the USA with a visa?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens

I have a US visa. The photo in this visa has hair. If I shave my head before traveling to the USA, will I encounter a problem at US immigration?

Comment: To those voting to close as off-topic, surely the precise type of the visa is irrelevant to the question. Can we please not have this knee-jerk reaction to close as off-topic for something that makes no difference to the actual question?

Comment: @DavidRicherby one can always remove the "offending" material.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to not shave your head until after you arrive in the US?

Comment: yes, because i am undertaking a minor surgery, i need to shave, but worried about the consequences if any

Comment: Immigration officers are able to tell whether you are the same person from your photograph, despite hairstyle changes.

Comment: oh that's great...bit relieved now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can shaving my head cause problems entering the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/can-shaving-my-head-cause-problems-entering-the-us)

Comment: @phoog I could, but education people that it isn't even "offensive" means we don't have to edit every time.

Comment: @phoog Well, it seems that even editing the type of visa out of the question isn't enough to stop people voting to close. Ridiculous. (Oh, or is this the annoying thing where the quoted close reason is the most common one that people voted for, even if people voted to close for other reasons, too.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I suspect it's the fact that three or four people voted to close in favor of Expatriates, but then one or two noticed the duplicate and voted for that.  Majority rules!  It would make much more sense to me to report all the vote reasons rather than just the most common one.

Comment: @DJClayworth "from your photograph": and, nowadays, from biometric data such as fingerprints that are stored in some passports.